# Are there 90% more computer science students and 90% fewer electrical engineering students than 50 years ago?

Tags: united-states, education

[This article](https://www.theregister.com/2022/07/18/electrical_engineers_extinction/) makes the claim that:

> While computer science course take-up had gone up by over 90 percent in the past 50 years, electrical engineering (EE) had declined by the same amount. The electronics graduate has become rarer than an Intel-based smartphone.

While I understand that Computer Science is a highly popular field, has there really been such a drastic change in the number of CS vs EE students? Is there any data to substantiate this claim?

Comment: What country is this claim about? Mkay it seems to be about the US https://www.theregister.com/2022/07/08/semiconductor_engineer_shortage/

Comment: FYI - I graduated from MIT about 50 years ago in 1970 and there was no such thing as majoring in computer science or getting a degree in the subject. I followed a newly existing path petitioning to have classes in computability, modern algebra, etc, substituted for classes in  antennas and waveguides to get an EE degree.

Comment: Yeah, I graduated in electrical engineering in 1972.  That was the first year that my college offered a computer science degree.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I don't know where you went to college, but your alma mater's computer science department most likely was spun off from its electrical engineering department. That's how the comp sci department at my alma mater formed, shortly before I started college the year after you graduated.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Speed Scientific School at the University of Louisville.  Yep, the comp sci department was gradually spun off of the EE department, first just producing "specialists" (I forget the term they used) with EE degrees.

Comment: From a European perspective. I know many who got a degree in electrical engineering between the 90's and the first decade of this century who worked and are still working as software developers. I suspect that a change in students proportion will not affect so much a change in the proportions of jobs.

Comment: My alma mater graduated its first class of CS B.Sc.'s in... 1977 I think, somewhere between 10 and 20 people, compared to well over a 100 of EE B.Sc.'s. Today I think about 200 or so of each of EE and CS graduate per year. Based on rough recollection of statistics and graduation photos.

Comment: My uni (Cantab) started offering Computer Science in my last year, which was 1978, I think. I turned down the chance because they were still using teletypes... more fool me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Not in absolute numbers, but possibly in *percentage points*.

The origin of the claim comes from a presentation by [Raja Koduri](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/newsroom/biographies/biography-raja-m-koduri.html) at Intel during a panel titled [*Building the 2030 Workforce: How to attract great students and what to teach them?*](https://www.vlsisymposium.org/evening-panels/) at the [2022 IEEE Symposium on VLSI Technology & Circuits](https://www.vlsisymposium.org/).

The original presentation does not seem to be freely available (yet) but the slide is available at [SemiWiki](https://semiwiki.com/events/314964-a-crisis-in-engineering-education-where-are-the-microelectronics-engineers/):

[image: College Enrollment: EE vs CS]

Since the original presentation is not available, I could not find exactly *how* this data is measured or what the source is, but speaking as an EE it does not seem surprising and matches what my colleagues and the head of the EE department at my university told us.

Comment: It's not your fault, but without context this chart is just weird and incomprehensible. What does "popularity" (in percent) mean? It can't be showing the relative popularity of EE and CS because then, the two lines would have to add up to 100 percent at any time. It can't be showing the changes in EE popularity and CS popularity relative to 1964, because they both would have to start at 100 percent. The only way this makes sense to me would be if it was showing enrollment in one specific college that only offered EE in 1964 but expanded to offer CS and other undisclosed subjects over time.

Comment: @Schmuddi I agree with all your objections, and hopefully the full presentation will be released with more information. I still think this answers the question and clears up some of the confusion. I just now noticed the _very faint_ watermark that looks like _Source: U.S. Dept. of Education ????_. Couldn't make anything out of that.